# HTML images that keep refreshing themselves

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to put up a dashboard with a number of images of data which change every couple of seconds. So I need to keep updating the `src` of the images, to include a change, for example if an image is at `/images/graph1.png`, after 10 seconds I would update it to `/images/graph1.png?a=1`, and then just keep changing the value of `a` every 10 seconds.

So the way I thought I should solve this best, in a uniformed and modular way, is with a directive. But I don't know how to change the variable value **from** the directive, that I've passed to it.

```
App.directive("updatable", function($interval){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: (function(){
            // Can I change the image source here...?
        }),
        replace: true,
        template: "<img src='{{ src }}'/>"
    }
});
```

The only thing I've found is that there is a way to access the values passed as parameters, in the `link` function, by accessing the `$observe` object, and then watch for changes. But I can't initiate the change from the directive.

So in this case, I would place the image in the document like so:

`<updatable src="{{ graphSource }}"></updatable>`

And ideally, what I was hoping to put in the `link` function would be something along the lines of:

```
if(scope.src.indexOf('?') == -1) {
    scope.src+= "?a=";
}
scope.src+= "1";
```

Anything just to change the `src` really. But this code doesn't work of course.

Is there a solution to this in a directive context, or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: In your link function scope, element and attributes are already passed in by default. Try using that. `link:function(scope, element, attrs){}` . Also one question, you have not isolated scope of your directive, So what will happen if I place multiple <updatable> in document ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a local src to solve the problem.

```js
const App = angular.module("a", []);

App.directive("updatable", ["$interval", function($interval) {
  return {
    scope: {
      "origin": "<originalSrc"
    },
    restrict: "E",
    link: (function(scope, element) {
      const src1 = "?a=";
      let cnt = 1;

      function update() {
        scope.src = src1 + cnt;
        cnt++;
      }
      update();
      $interval(update, 1000);

    }),
    replace: true,
    template: `
    <div>
      <label ng-bind="origin+src"></label>
      <img ng-src="{{origin+src}}" />
    </div>
    `
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="a">
  <updatable original-src="'http://example.com/a.jpg'">

  </updatable>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple directive for your like in this [runnable fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gtmtzrcf/). The image source and the interval duration could be configured by attributes: `src-image` & `interval` directly in the directive HTML element. Its working just fine =)

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="email_log_container"> 
    <img src-image="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=150%C3%97150&w=150&h=150" 
         interval="10000" 
         height="50" 
         width="50"
         updatable /> 
  </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
});

myApp.directive('updatable ', function ($interval) {
  return{
    restrict:'A',
    link:function(scope, element, attr){
      var i = 0;
      attr.$set('src', attr.srcImage + '&a=' + i); //init
      $interval(function() {
        attr.$set('src', attr.srcImage + '&a=' + i);
        i++;
      }, attr.interval);            
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is the code that I came up with:

**HTML:**

```
<img src="https://blog.apnic.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/https-1.jpg" updatable interval="10000">
```

**Javascript**

```
app.directive('updatable', function($interval) {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      var currentStep = 1;
      var initialSrc = element[0].src;
      var interval = typeof attrs.interval === 'undefined' ? 10000 : parseInt(attrs.interval);

      $interval(function() {

        element[0].src = initialSrc + '?a=' + currentStep;
        currentStep++;
        console.log(element[0].src);

      }, interval);

    }
  };
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxznca14/3/)

I'm sure that there can be a lot of different implementations